# is it wise to call your own application api in your controller in loop?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an application that in a controller I am trying to send some `room id` and some date  for each day I want to loop and for each room now the problem is when I run this query below :

```
  $from_date = $request->get('from_date');
  $to_date = $request->get('to_date');
  $room_ids[] = $request->get('room_ids');

  $period = CarbonPeriod::create($from_date, $to_date);
  $dates = $period->toArray();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {

            for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_ids); $f++) {

                /****************************************
                 * Looping for the Number of Rooms User Given
                 *****************************************/
                $room_price = RoomPricingHistory::with('accommodationRoom', 'accommodationRoom.roomCapacityHistoryLast')
                    ->where('accommodation_room_id', $room_ids[$i])
                    ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$f])
                    ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$f])
                    ->get()->sortBy('created_at');
                var_dump('time');

                $data_array[] = $room_price[$i];
                $data_collection = collect($data_array);

                $sum_price[] = $room_price[$i]->sales_price; // trying to get and store data not to be replaced after each step of loop
                $sum_half_board[] = $room_price[$i]->half_charge_price;
                $sum_full_board[] = $room_price[$i]->full_board_price;
            }
        }
        foreach ($room_price as $item) {
            if ($item->accommodationRoom->roomCapacityHistoryLast->capacity > 10 ?? null) {
                $check_capacity = 0;
            } else {
                $check_capacity = 1;
            }
        }
        $night_count = count($dates);
        $sum = array_sum($sum_price);
        $sum_half = array_sum($sum_half_board);
        $sum_full = array_sum($sum_full_board);

        $alldata = $sum . ',' . $sum_half . ',' . $sum_full . ',' . $night_count . ',' . $check_capacity;
        return RoomDetailResource::collection($data_collection)->sum($alldata);
```

I get this error :

```
  "message": "Undefined offset: 1",
    "status_code": 500,
```

I think its because 1 loop runs more than once now my question is call I make 1 for and make an api from it and then in another function call that api whithin a loop and get the result ??

Is it wise to do such or we sould not call our own api in our own project ??

or if there is any way to solve this error above ??

Comment: Remove `[]` from `$room_ids[] = $request->get('room_ids');`. This syntax means pushing values in the next index. So, `$roos_ids[0]` will receive data. And you will get values from this data only via `$rooms_ids[0]['blabla']`

Comment: You are accessing array values of $dates with index that is only relevant to $room_ids ($dates[$f]). If there is only 1 date but multiple rooms you will get undefined index error.

Comment: @geldek how can i make that work ?? cause yes i know the problem is with the different number of days and rooms

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[]` from `$room_ids[] = $request->get('room_ids');`.
This syntax means pushing values in the next index.

Thus, your `$room_ids` will has filled `$room_ids[0]` with received data and `count($room_ids)` will be equal to `1`, but `count($dates)` could be more then `1`, so, `$room_ids[$i]` will receive next `$i` and thus the `$room_ids[1]` will be undefined.

Also, you're using `$dates[$f]` when it supposed to be `$dates[$i]` and also `$room_ids[$i]` perhaps should be `$room_ids[$f]`.

Next step, `$room_price[$i];` means that `$room_price` should be an array and `$i` is a counter of `$dates` array(from prev for loop), be careful with it. This means, that length of `$dates` should be the same as length of `$room_price`, which you've received from database.

Comment: i did as you said but yet again i get the error `"message": "Undefined offset: 1",
    "status_code": 500,`

Comment: @Farshad, Why you're using `$dates[$f]` when it supposed to be `$dates[$i]`? And also `$room_ids[$i]` perhaps should be `$room_ids[$f]`?

Comment: i did as you said sir but again problem exist

Comment: @Farshad, then I need to see your data. A few rows at least for each variable. It should be `$dates`, `$room_price`, `$room_ids` By the way, you're using here only one value `->whereDate`. Somewhere you have an `invalid index 1`. You will define where is it when you'll see this data.

Comment: how you need the data can you make some any desk to my pc or something ??

Comment: @Farshad, no, I don't need this)) Just make `print_r($dates); return;` after `$dates` and show the result here via updating your answer. This was an example.